# View PHP (echo) output in Sublime Text 2 when the code is run from Android

Tags: php, android, echo

I have an android app that runs a PHP script to insert some rows into a MySQL table on my home server. I need to perform some debugging for which I have placed some "echo" commands at strategic locations within my PHP script. However, since the script is being triggered by an Android app on my phone, I obviously can't view the results of those echo commands in my browser. Is there any workaround?

For what it's worth, here's the PHP script in question:

```
<?php
// Includes
    require_once 'PROJdbconn.php';

// Run script only if the dump array is received
if($_POST){ 
    echo "\nEntries received: ".count($_POST)."\n"; // TEST1: Get POST size

// Read POST array
    $arr = 0;
    foreach($_POST as $entry){
        $tempentry = $entry;
        $namenum = explode(",",$tempentry);
        $names[$arr] = str_replace("_", " ", $namenum[1]);
        $numbers[$arr] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$namenum[0]);
        $arr += 1;
    }
    $namenum = NULL;
    echo "\nEntries after parse: ".$arr."\n\n"; // TEST2: Get parse count

// Build SQL query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Contact_table (PHONE, NAME) VALUES ";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arr; ++$i){
        $sql .= "('".$numbers[$i]."', '".$names[$i]."'),";
        echo $i.". ".$numbers[$i]."--->".$names[$i]."\n"; // TEST3: dump names and numbers
    }
    $i = NULL;
    $arr = NULL;
    $names = NULL;
    $numbers = NULL;
    $sql = substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-1)." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = COALESCE(VALUES(name), name);";

// Connect to MySQL database
    $connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,PROJDB,PROJDBUSER,PROJDBPWD);

// Execute SQL query
    $query = $connect->query($sql);
    $sql = NULL;
    $query = NULL;

// Close connection to MySQL database
    $connect = NULL;
}
?>
```

Comment: can't you write the echos in a file instead? maybe have a read on [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) I think you can direct the content into a file

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Every good android client that posts to a script will read the output/echos of the script too. And why wouldnt a browser be able to display these echos?

Comment: A browser can't display the echos returned by a script it's not triggering in the first place. As I said, the script is being called by an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a google chrome extension that can POST data to this PHP script. the extensions name is **Postman - REST Client**. Its a very easy tool to use :).